Tailwind CSS IntelliSense doesn't suggest the CSS classes in NX monorepo anymore
My NX monorepo workspace is based on Angular, and I have tailwind.config.js for my apps. Everything was cool, and Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension was suggesting the available CSS classes in my workspace... But since I updated the extension to v0.12.7, the suggestion box is not coming up anymore. Does anyone know how can we fix it?
I also have added the following config in me.code-workspace file, but still no chance:
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "strings": "on"
},
"files.associations": {
      "*.css": "tailwindcss",
      "*.scss": "tailwindcss"
},


A quick peak into the "Issues" part of the extensions repository will tell you that apparently the intellisense is broken for versions >= 0.12.7.
See this issue for example. Downgrade to 0.12.6 or wait for a new version in which it is fixed.
